# How to vary the thickness of a Bezier curve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I have made a bezier tube and I want some parts of it to be large and others to be small.

When I try to set the depth for one of its vertices, it just changes the depth for the whole object. Is there a way to change the depth for separate parts of the bezier curve?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Vertex Radius

You can scale the thickness of a curve at the selected vertices with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> in edit mode.

## Taper Objects

You can also use a [*Taper object*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Curves#Geometry):

[image]

The distance from the object origin (yellow dot) in the local Y direction controls the width of the main curve:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't get the Vertex Radius answer to work for me...could you elaborate? It sounds like a great technique!

Comment: Alt s just seems to make the hairs of the bezier grow longer, but your other way worked :)

Comment: @Zachooz It sounds like the shortcut wasn't working correctly (what you described sounds like the normal behavior scaling with `S`). Does it work if you press *Shink Fatten* in *3D view > Tool shelf (`T`) > Tool tab > Transform*?

Comment: @Gandalf I saw my problem :D It actually works but I was also linking it to a tapered object so they were conflicting.

Answer (score 3):

in b2.93 use
Alt+S
on the curve vertex. Also if you use Taper Object then make sure to set Taper Radius to multiply.

[image]