# How to create a curved side in a cylinder

Tags: modeling

I want to model this:

[image: cylinder with round sides]

Ignoring the upper and lower parts and focusing only on the tapered sides of the cylinder, how can I get a cylinder to have that shape?

I've tried several things:

1. Add a few horizontal loop cuts and try to scale it in with proportional editing turned on and set to sphere.
2. Boolean operation - I created a second cylinder, rotated it and brought it in close to the main cylinder and applied a 'difference' boolean operation. It worked - the sides looked like I wanted them to, but the mesh became a mess and I couldn't find a way to fix it. I used the knife tool to connect a few vertices and ended up with a mix of polys and tries that looked terrible.
3. Tried a few other things that I am embarrassed to admit I did lol.

Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69411/what-would-be-a-simple-way-to-model-a-curved-funnel/69416 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90963/how-to-create-a-rounded-cone

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114490/twisted-cylinder-hyperboloid-of-one-sheet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do it with *Proportional Editing* but you can also create an edge loop, scale it down:

[image]

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel, you can tweak some parameters in the *Operator* box:

[image]

Comment: I cannot believe this. I was just missing enough loop cuts - I added a number of them with the bevel tool and proportional editing worked. I've been trying to do this since yesterday and it was an absurdly simple thing. I should give up on learning Blender lol Thanks @moonboots!

Comment: It's happened to everyone. :D You'll never forget about proportional edit now

Comment: @antidextrous You're doing fine, everyone here gets schooled by moonboots at some point :D

Comment: ^^ come on, this one was easy, but yes sometimes you forget the easiest way. By the way, Antidextrous, you don't need Proportional Editing here, just bevel, but of course you can also use Proportional Editing if you want