# Blender curve vertices

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, vertices

I am fairly new to 3d modeling and I am trying to make an array of vertices curved. When I searched how to do this, people suggest I use the bevel tool but nothing is happening when I try to use it.

[image]

Is there a way I can do this without manually transforming each vertex?

Context: I am trying to make a watermill wheel.

Comment: Hi :). This answer covers a very similar case [How to create a curved side in a cylinder](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/238498/78972)

Comment: Yes, the bevel tool works well when you have a simple object like a cube or cylinder or a mesh but it's not working on a face. At least I can't get it working

Comment: Hi Stan :). Since your edge is already subdivided, you can use proportional editing instead.