# How to animate cubes coming out of a mesh - like fire?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, particles

Ok, I dont know how to describe this other than a low poly fire sort of deal - imagine this

[image]

but animated, so with a particle system of the cubes constantly separating/floating out of the big mesh: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypRlkByjSbA

Normally what I would do is just animate like 3 cubes as separate objects moving in a loop "out" of the base object, but I have a transparent material and need to make it look like parts of the base are ripping away:

[image]

How can I do this? Im in cycles

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112746/atmospheric-trail/112753#112753