# Molecule raster like particle movement?

Tags: particles

Is is possible to make particles stay kind of in place but move around like molecules do in a solid state? kinda like vibrate a bit? couldn't find anything about this, found a force that I think does it (something with molecule) but I tried it and couldn't get it to work. Thanks in advance! (and no I don't want brownian motion, particles need to stay near their original position)

Comment: Will this setup work for you? http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50600

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112746/atmospheric-trail/112753#112753