# how to create a light streak(trail) in Blender 2.8?

Tags: particles, light

Does anyone know how to create a light streak(trail) in Blender 2.8?  this following tutorial shows how to do it in an earlier version of Blender, but I could not make the smooth light streaks in the 2.8 version.  The light streaks came out as a bunch of particles, not smooth.  Thank you.

https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=how+to+create+a+light+streak+in+blender&docid=608041268300154275&mid=3CBA7361FBC00C4E69C43CBA7361FBC00C4E69C4&view=detail&FORM=VIREHT

Comment: related: [How do I create light steaks in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34377/how-can-i-create-light-streaks-in-cycles/34383#34383)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos note that the proposed duplicate is not dealing with particles.

Comment: Here are a couple more some dealing with particles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93921/how-to-add-trailing-light-effect-to-finger-tips/94976#94976 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112746/atmospheric-trail/112753#112753

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to a similar post.  It really helped.