# How can I (easily) create particles falling from the ground

Tags: animation

I am creating a very low poly, very simple rocket take off animation for a college assignment. I cannot figure out how to make particles fall from the rockets engine no matter how many youtube tutorials I follow. Frankly, I don't even know where to start with it. [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112746/atmospheric-trail/112753#112753

Answer (score 1):

Make particles fall off from the engine is a rather easy task.

- you need to define some faces as the emitter, for example, the rocket engine. Assign the faces to a *Vertex Group*. **Alternatively** create a simple object (circle) that is used as an emitter, place it in front of the rocket engine, and parent it to the rocket. The extra object can be excluded from render (*Particle Properties > Render > [_] Show Emitter*).
- add an *Ico Sphere* (very low-poly, just 1 subdivision in create popup dialog), scale it down to 1 cm. This is your particle object. Give it a material with an Emission to make it glow. Enable `Bloom` in Eevee
- add the *Particle System* to the rocket and adjust a few settings:

  - type is `Emitter`, increase the *Number* of particles to something like `5000`, and set *Lifetime* to `20` (or higher for a longer tail), *Frame Start* to `1`, *End* to `200`
  - set *Velocity > Normal* to `10 m/s` to speed up the particles, and *Velocity > Object Velocity* to something like `0.482`. This makes the tail a little "fringy"
  - in the section *Physics > Forces* give the particles some *Damp*, like `0.121`, so they don't bounce around like crazy.
  - in *Render* set *Render As* to `Object`, set *Scale* to `1.0` (adjust if needed), and select the `particle object` (Ico Sphere) as *Render > Object > Instance Object*
  - if you have defined a vertex group for the emitting faces you can specify it under *Vertex Groups > Density*.

[image: Vertex group for emitter]

Have a good rocket launch!

[image: rocket launch]