# How can I make a moving object kick up dirt?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, smoke-simulation

I am rendering out an animation of an x-wing and a tie fighter having a dogfight close to the ground in a desert and I need them to kick up dirt behind them. I don't need it to actually make the ships dirty or anthing just to make a plume of dust and dirt that follows the ships.Here are some examples:

[image: Ships kick up dirt behind them.]

[image: More accurate picture of what I need]

I am using Cycles to render this so it needs to work with that. So far I haven't found any answers on how to do this so if anyone knows please tell me.

Comment: I would say dynamic paint and a smoke simulation. However, smoke simulation may be to computationally extensive for the size you would need, so you might go with a particle system and smoke cards instead. Still dynamic paint, though.

Comment: yes for something realistic, smoke simulation seems like the way to go

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112746/atmospheric-trail/112753#112753

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Blender 3.1 you might want to use [Point Info](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/render/shader_nodes/input/point_info.html) to create a point cloud for something like a sandstorm.

The traditional approach, which is much more GPU/CPU intense is to use a particle simulation.

You can find online tutorials for either. The first is featured in the Foundation's "What's new" reel for 3.1