# How to make trails that look like this below?

Tags: animation, node-editor, bezier-curves, effects

I'm trying to remake this logo from Hanna-Barbera in Blender 2.79.

[image]

I've tried using a Bezier Curve with the rectangle trail effect inside, but it just doesn't work. I know how to use Nodes, so I am planning to use a Color Ramp on the trail. The file isn't finished yet, but I would kindly like some solutions.

Comment: You've tagged your question in the Animation category, do you plan to animate it?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93921/how-to-add-trailing-light-effect-to-finger-tips

Comment: There is a free addon included in Blender called Btracer (Edit > Preferences >Addon>Btrace) that could help you [Example](https://imgur.com/a/zb15E64)

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with a curve, go into the *Object Data panel > Geometry*, give it a *Bevel Object* (which will be its profile) and a *Taper Object* (which will define the thickness along the curve)

[image]

[image]