# Converting Motion Paths to Curves

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm currently animating a moving object and I wanted to add a trail behind it using [this method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpXz0u3SYk4&t), but when making the curve for the Motion Path I've found no way of automatically converting the Motion Path to a curve.

Manually setting up the curve could work but it would get harder the more objects I'm trying to make trails for.
Is there any way to automatically convert the Motion Path to a Curve? Maybe through some sort of addon.

Comment: May be this answer could help you https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/94976/115533 ?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: yes, it is much easier with animation nodes and the bluefox extension link here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQyBF9FLwbA&t=2s just by using 3 nodes you will get your curve