# How do you make bones follow each other in an After Effect like way?

Tags: bones, constraints

The After Effect way is something like a sword trail or the Tron bike trail effects.

The trail is a plane mesh connected to bones and it's just like a gradient. All I need is to get the bones to trail behind the root bone.

I have tried all the tracking constraints in different ways but they all end up breaking.

Comment: Hello, it seems a bit vague, what is the after effect way?

Comment: Something like a sword trail or the tron bike trail effects.

Comment: so maybe instead of bones use a Curve modifier for example? do you have pictures of the effect you're looking for?

Comment: The trail is a plane mesh connected to bones and it's just like a gradient. All i need is to get the bones to trail behind the root bone.

Comment: maybe this would help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133012/line-of-bones-to-travel-and-conform-to-curve-train-or-snake-following-path ... but maybe you could even use a Curve modifier with no bone?

Comment: A similar question about trails but no bones: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/93921/107598